# css doing nothing - referencing issue - font awesome icon - react

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome-5

I will probably feel silly when this gets answered but can't work out why this is not working? FA icon appears but can't reference it in CSS to make changes. Keep trying different things and can't change my icon in my NavBar component in my css? Have tried nav .burger too. Any pointers to the stupid mistake I am making here?

In NavBar

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function NavBar() {

    return(
        <nav>
        <ul activeclassname="nav">
            <li id ="name">
                <Link exact to="/">Barry Jones</Link>
            </li>
            <li activeclassname="active">
                <NavLink exact to="/">HOME</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li activeclassname="active">
                <NavLink exact to="/about">ABOUT</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li activeclassname="active">
                <NavLink exact to="/portfolio">PROJECTS</NavLink>
                
            </li>
            <li activeclassname ="active">
                <NavLink exact to="/cv">CV</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li activeclassname = "active">
                <NavLink exact to="/blog">BLOG</NavLink>
            </li>
    
            <i className="fas fa-bars burger"></i>
        </ul>
    </nav>     

    );
}

 
export default NavBar;
```

Btw, not sure why I added the nav tags - Had it without this before but started following alongside tutorials to get this working and just tried that to see if it made a difference.

Yeah btw, I do want the bars not the hamburger - I don't know why I'm calling it burger lol.

CSS (I can't get it to do anything - does nothing)

```
   .burger{
        font-size: 400px;
      }
```

Thanks to the people that took the time to answer this as all info is helpful. Turns out that my css was accidentally nested inside a media query and did change upon screen size change. Just a silly mistake!

Comment: The CSS is definitely applied to the page with the FA icon?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest font-awesome, then the syntax for burger icon is `<i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i>`
Link: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/hamburger?style=solid

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome has an official React component to easily the icons https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Answer (score 0):

you can also try directly adding the size in the icon element like

```
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-xs"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-sm"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-lg"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-3x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-5x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-7x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-10x"></i>
```

https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons